# Problem after NVIDIA proprietary driver update - Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I'm using a laptop in which I have both an NVIDIA graphic card and the Intel integrated one. Before I updated the NVIDIA driver through Linux Mint update manager, I used to have them both configured using NVIDIA settings and NVIDIA Prime.

After the update the driver manager marks the NVIDIA driver as installed, but the Intel graphic card has the following sentence written below "This device is not working" and the only option possible is "Do not use this device".
Both `xserver-xorg-video-intel`, `mesa-utils` and `nvidia-settings` are still installed (I've also tried to reinstall them) and I have SeureBoot disabled. When I try to run `nvidia-settings` it return an empty page and the following error is displayed:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

ERROR: Unable to load info from any available system
```

How can I fix this situation?
Thanks!

This is the output from `lspci -nnk | grep "VGA\|'Kern'\|3D\|Display" -A2`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e9b]
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:1fc0]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
--
01:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [10de:1c8d] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] [1043:1fc0]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau, nvidia_drm, nvidia
```

From `ls /lib/modprobe.d/`:

```
aliases.conf                             blacklist-nvidia.conf
blacklist_linux_4.15.0-106-generic.conf  fbdev-blacklist.conf
blacklist_linux_4.15.0-112-generic.conf  nvidia-graphics-drivers.conf
blacklist_linux_4.15.0-20-generic.conf   nvidia-kms.conf
blacklist_linux_4.15.0-54-generic.conf   systemd.conf
```

From `dpkg -l | grep -i nvidia`:

```
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-440:amd64                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-common-440                       440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
rc  libnvidia-compute-390:i386                 390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:amd64                440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-compute-440:i386                 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:amd64                 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-decode-440:i386                  440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:amd64                 440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-encode-440:i386                  440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-extra-440:amd64                  440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        Extra libraries for the NVIDIA driver
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:amd64                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-440:i386                    440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:amd64                     440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-gl-440:i386                      440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:amd64                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-440:i386                    440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         i386         NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
rc  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-440                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
rc  nvidia-dkms-390                            390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-dkms-440                            440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA DKMS package
ii  nvidia-driver-440                          440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
rc  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.138-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-440                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-440                   440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.8.2                                          all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-prime-applet                        1.0.7                                            all          An applet for NVIDIA Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            440.44-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                          amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-440                           440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-440              440.100-0ubuntu0.18.04.1                         amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Here are my system info:

```
System:    Host: marco-ASUS Kernel: 4.15.0-112-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 
           Desktop: Cinnamon 4.2.4 wm: marco dm: LightDM Distro: Linux Mint 19.2 Tina 
           base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: VivoBook_ASUSLaptop X580GD_N580GD v: 1.0 
           serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X580GD v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends 
           v: X580GD.304 date: 05/17/2018 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 29.1 Wh condition: 30.4/48.1 Wh (63%) volts: 11.6/11.6 
           model: ASUSTeK ASUS Battery serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: 6-Core model: Intel Core i7-8750H bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Kaby Lake 
           rev: A L2 cache: 9216 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 52799 
           Speed: 4004 MHz min/max: 800/4100 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 3987 2: 4045 3: 4000 
           4: 4000 5: 4005 6: 4013 7: 3943 8: 4002 9: 4000 10: 4006 11: 3991 12: 4038 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
           chip ID: 8086:3e9b 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile] vendor: ASUSTeK driver: N/A 
           bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 10de:1c8d 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa 
           compositor: marco resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.8 
           compat-v: 3.0 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:1f.3 chip ID: 8086:a348 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-112-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wireless-AC 9560 [Jefferson Peak] driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: 5000 
           bus ID: 00:14.3 chip ID: 8086:a370 
           IF: wlo1 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK 
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 3000 bus ID: 03:00.0 chip ID: 10ec:8168 
           IF: eno2 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 931.51 GiB used: 539.31 GiB (57.9%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Toshiba model: MQ04ABF100 size: 931.51 GiB speed: 6.0 Gb/s 
           serial: <filter> 
RAID:      Hardware-1: Intel 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] driver: ahci v: 3.0 
           bus ID: 00:17.0 chip ID: 8086.282a 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 136.93 GiB used: 111.72 GiB (81.6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda1 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 31.25 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda2 
USB:       Hub: 1-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 16 rev: 2.0 chip ID: 1d6b:0002 
           Device-1: 1-2:2 info: Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse type: Mouse 
           driver: hid-generic,usbhid rev: 1.1 chip ID: 045e:0084 
           Device-2: 1-6:3 info: IMC Networks type: Video driver: uvcvideo rev: 2.0 
           chip ID: 13d3:56a2 
           Device-3: 1-7:4 info: Realtek RTS5129 Card Reader Controller type: <vendor specific> 
           driver: rtsx_usb,rtsx_usb_ms,rtsx_usb_sdmmc rev: 2.0 chip ID: 0bda:0129 
           Device-4: 1-14:5 info: Intel type: Bluetooth driver: btusb rev: 2.0 chip ID: 8087:0aaa 
           Hub: 2-0:1 info: Full speed (or root) Hub ports: 8 rev: 3.1 chip ID: 1d6b:0003 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 68.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
```

Comment: Please try asking at https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: I've posted there as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the same problem on ubuntu 18.04.
it appears the headers for kernel 4.15.0-112-generic did not install/update.
To fix this just run command:

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-112-generic linux-headers-4.15.0-112-generic
```

And reboot